# issue with java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement to oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have been trying to run JPA 2.0 in Tomcat 6.0.24 following this tutorial online:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial

So far it worked to retrieve a datasource and run a select statement. 
    Query aQuery = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e");
    empList = aQuery.getResultList();

But it failed when I tried to call entityManager.persist(employee). The code looked like this:

```
try {
em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(emp);
em.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
em.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

I am getting this exception in the console:

```
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.38--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit jpaOrclJtaPU; session file:/C:/eclipseProjects/workspaces/JPA4ORCL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JPAStruts1310Web/WEB-INF/classes/_jpaOrclJtaPU; state Initial; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: properties: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.396--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--property=eclipselink.orm.throw.exceptions; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.397--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--property=eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-emf; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.397--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--property=eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache; default value=false
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.422--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/C:/eclipseProjects/workspaces/JPA4ORCL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JPAStruts1310Web/WEB-INF/classes/ (There is no English translation for this message.)
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.428--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/C:/eclipseProjects/workspaces/JPA4ORCL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JPAStruts1310Web/WEB-INF/classes/ (There is no English translation for this message.)
[EL Config]: metadata: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.606--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class com.arb.my.domain.Employee] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: metadata: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.637--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class com.arb.my.domain.Employee] is being defaulted to: Employee.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.64--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--The table name for entity [class com.arb.my.domain.Employee] is being defaulted to: EMPLOYEE.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.672--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit jpaOrclJtaPU; session file:/C:/eclipseProjects/workspaces/JPA4ORCL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JPAStruts1310Web/WEB-INF/classes/_jpaOrclJtaPU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finer]: weaver: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.673--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--JavaSECMPInitializer - transformer is null.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.673--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit jpaOrclJtaPU; session file:/C:/eclipseProjects/workspaces/JPA4ORCL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JPAStruts1310Web/WEB-INF/classes/_jpaOrclJtaPU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.673--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit jpaOrclJtaPU; session file:/C:/eclipseProjects/workspaces/JPA4ORCL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JPAStruts1310Web/WEB-INF/classes/_jpaOrclJtaPU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.683--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Begin deploying Persistence Unit jpaOrclJtaPU; session file:/C:/eclipseProjects/workspaces/JPA4ORCL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JPAStruts1310Web/WEB-INF/classes/_jpaOrclJtaPU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finer]: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.692--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Could not initialize Validation Factory. Encountered following exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation
[EL Finest]: properties: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.696--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=FINEST; translated value=FINEST
[EL Finest]: properties: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.696--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=FINEST; translated value=FINEST
[EL Finest]: properties: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.696--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--property=eclipselink.target-database; value=Oracle11; translated value=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform
[EL Finest]: properties: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.712--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--property=eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing; value=Oracle-JDBC; translated value=Oracle-JDBC
[EL Finest]: properties: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.713--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--property=eclipselink.session.customizer; value=com.arb.my.util.JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer
_JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer: configured java:comp/env/jdbc/EmployeeDS
[EL Info]: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.717--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
[EL Config]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:16.806--ServerSession(10229612)--Connection(25559254)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>Oracle11Platform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>java:comp/env/jdbc/EmployeeDS
))
[EL Config]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.121--ServerSession(10229612)--Connection(8689654)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe
    User: MH
    Database: Oracle  Version: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Beta
    Driver: Oracle JDBC driver  Version: 11.2.0.2.0
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.121--ServerSession(10229612)--Connection(18129670)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.122--ServerSession(10229612)--Connection(18129670)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].
[EL Config]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.122--ServerSession(10229612)--Connection(31133089)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>Oracle11Platform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>java:comp/env/jdbc/EmployeeDS
))
[EL Config]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.122--ServerSession(10229612)--Connection(6019448)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe
    User: MH
    Database: Oracle  Version: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Beta
    Driver: Oracle JDBC driver  Version: 11.2.0.2.0
[EL Info]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.632--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--file:/C:/eclipseProjects/workspaces/JPA4ORCL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JPAStruts1310Web/WEB-INF/classes/_jpaOrclJtaPU login successful
[EL Finer]: metamodel: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.658--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Canonical Metamodel class [com.arb.my.domain.Employee_] not found during initialization.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.658--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--End deploying Persistence Unit jpaOrclJtaPU; session file:/C:/eclipseProjects/workspaces/JPA4ORCL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/JPAStruts1310Web/WEB-INF/classes/_jpaOrclJtaPU; state Deployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finer]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.679--ServerSession(10229612)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--client acquired: 7060068
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.692--ClientSession(7060068)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 9790036
[EL Finest]: transaction: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.692--UnitOfWork(9790036)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--persist() operation called on: com.arb.my.domain.Employee@16aa42e.
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.694--UnitOfWork(9790036)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--begin unit of work commit
[EL Finest]: query: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.702--UnitOfWork(9790036)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(com.arb.my.domain.Employee@16aa42e)
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.704--ServerSession(10229612)--Connection(21263661)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.704--ClientSession(7060068)--Connection(21263661)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--begin transaction
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.705--ClientSession(7060068)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Finer]: sql: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.705--ClientSession(7060068)--Connection(23651369)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Begin batch statements
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.706--ClientSession(7060068)--Connection(23651369)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EMP_NO, EMP_FNAME, EMP_LNAME, JOIN_DATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.706--ClientSession(7060068)--Connection(23651369)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--    bind => [4, Issa, Haque, null]
[EL Finer]: sql: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.706--ClientSession(7060068)--Connection(23651369)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--End Batch Statements
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.831--ClientSession(7060068)--Connection(23651369)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--rollback transaction
[EL Finest]: connection: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.832--ServerSession(10229612)--Connection(21263661)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Warning]: 2012-12-08 16:17:17.832--UnitOfWork(9790036)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8082-exec-4,5,main])--java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement
    at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform.prepareBatchStatement(Oracle9Platform.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.prepareBatchStatements(ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.executeBatchedStatements(ParameterizedSQLBatchWritingMechanism.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.writesCompleted(DatabaseAccessor.java:1714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writesCompleted(AbstractSession.java:3951)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.writesCompleted(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5552)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.acquireWriteLocks(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitTransactionAfterWriteChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1592)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    at com.arb.my.domain.controller.EmployeeManager.createEmployee(EmployeeManager.java:44)
    at com.arb.my.action.EmployeeDetailAction.execute(EmployeeDetailAction.java:37)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any Idea why am I getting this exception? Any body else got this error before while running JPA? Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after banging my head for 72 hours, I figured it out myself (Patting myself on my back!)

I had this "Batch-writing" property to 'Oracle-JDBC' in persistence.xml. I changed it to 'JDBC' and it started working!

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    
    </persistence-unit>,     java:comp/env/-->
    
    org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
        java:comp/env/jdbc/EmployeeDS
        com.arb.my.domain.Employee

I hope it helps anybody who faces this issue in future.